# Rails 3.1 multiple controllers for one path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

We have two models, areas and stores, which we want to run off the same path: www.mysite.com/the_name_of_the_thing_here

What we would like to do is go through the areas table for a match to show the area page and, if there is no match, to go through the stores table and show the store page instead. We're not quite sure where to put this logic (in the areas controller?) and how to switch controllers. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use controller action for that, something like

```
@area = Area.find_by_name(params[:name])
@store = Store.find_by_name(params[:name])
if @area
  redirect_to area_path(@area)
elsif @store
  redirect_to store_path(@store)
else
  redirect_to help_url
end
```

If you want to change content only make other controller method in which you define variable:

```
@thing = Area.find_by_name(params[:name]) || Store.find_by_name(params[:name])
```

and pass it to view

```
<%= thing.name %>
```

Comment: hi alex, thanks for this. one question: would this not end up in a loop as the paths are identical?

Comment: hey again. unfortunately this requires the app to redirect to a different path for each model. i want to do this without redirects... i need it to check "the_name_of_the_thing_here" against the first model and then serve that model's view if there is a match, OR serve the second model's view if the match is only that second model...